# Past perfect continuous

Tags: past-tense, perfect-aspect, continuous-aspect

I'm confused about the past perfect continuous sentence. One YouTuber who is an English teacher is explaining that there is a slight difference between the following two sentences, which makes me confused.

1. It had been raining for two hours when I left the house.
2. It had been raining when I left the house.

In his explanation, in the sentence No.1, it was still raining when I left the house.

On the other hand, in the sentence No.2, he's saying that it stopped raining when I left the house, whuch means that I left home after it stopped raining.

In my understanding about the past perfect continuous, the moment when a past event happens should be included in the period where a continuous event keeps occurring.
So, I'm confused about this YouTuber's explanation of the sentence No.2 especially.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N2aXMCv1-WM&list=PLDGMxCuepbfEwKYHdRq_mdmZB765UwCzJ&index=10

Comment: I leave grammatical analysis to those more competent than I but I agree with your doubts about no. 2. For example, “It had been raining when I left the house, and it continued throughout the day.”

Comment: (2) _could_ mean that there were signs that it had rained earlier. Compare "Your hair looks damp. Have you been swimming?" (Have you recently left the swimming pool?)

Comment: Thank you for you comments, Kate and Anton. I can understand about the example using a present perfect continuous. "My hair looks damp, because I have been swimming." In this sentence, I am not swimming when I'm saying that.

Comment: Then, how about when we are talking about the past? In the following examples, was the continuous event still occurring when the second event happened? No.1 "My dad had been watching TV, when I came home." No.2 "My dad had been watching TV for 2 hours, when I came home."